# Using Google AI Platform to make text better?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, artificial-intelligence, google-ai-platform

So I am trying to turn lines of text that is supplied by 3rd parties into conversations.

For example say I have the following text

> Kwinana Fwy southbound After Roe Hwy Jandakot  - Road Crash

I need a system that can look at that and convert it to:

> Crash on Kwinana Fwy, southbound just after Roe Hwy.

I am looking at using Google AI (but I am not sure if this would be the best solution).

Also we have data like

> South St westbound Carrington St Hilton  - Miscellaneous - Left Lane(s) Blocked.  No Known Congestion.  Exercise Extreme Caution.

Clearly the main information needs to be:

> Left lanes blocked at South St, Westbound at Carrington Street, Hilton.

If anyone knows how we can get a computer to turn raw text into readable text that would be very helpful.

I understand we may need to train the system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AutoML Natural Language](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/quickstart#train_your_model) to train a machine learning custom model to classify, extract, and detect sentiment.